# What are the default values for frequency feature of a datapoint not found in training

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation

Given a dataset, I would like to use the frequency count of each element in a column. But if the testing data has a data point that is not found in training, how do I go about?
For example consider the column in the training data that has values 1,2,3,5,1,3
If there is a data point 4 in the testing data which is not found in the training data, what is the recommended approach?
 Some of the proposed techniques are:
1) If the column is numeric, then we can compute the average of the closest numbers. In the case of 4, the frequency is 1.5 .
2) default the frequency of all unknown values to 1.

What are the common techniques to apply to both numeric and non numeric values in this case?

Comment: What is your real problem, what is your goal?